# Как из IDE (java) выполнить SQL команду на изменение значения?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

Я пыталась из IDE выполнить в SQLite команду, которая меняла бы значение, если бы условие совпадало

```
package testanddelete;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class TestAndDelete {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TestAndDelete iCarly = new TestAndDelete();
        if (iCarly.open()) {
            iCarly.change();
            iCarly.getData();

            iCarly.close();
        }
    }

    Connection c;

    void change() {
        try {
            Statement statement = c.createStatement();
            String query = " SELECT  rusWord,  engWord , checkWord "
                    + " FROM words ";
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
            String rusWord = rs.getString("rusWord");
            String engWord = rs.getString("engWord");
            Boolean check = rs.getBoolean("checkWord");
            while (rs.next()) {

                if (rusWord.equals("a")) {
                    System.out.println("'" + rusWord + "' найдена");
                    rs.updateString("rusWord", "s");
                    rs.updateRow();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
        }
    }

    void getData() {
        try {
            Statement statement = c.createStatement();
            String query = " SELECT  rusWord,  engWord , checkWord "
                    + " FROM words " + "ORDER BY rusWord";
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {
                String rusWord = rs.getString("rusWord");
                String engWord = rs.getString("engWord");
                Boolean check = rs.getBoolean("checkWord");
                System.out.println(" | " + rusWord + "\t | " + engWord + "\t | " + check);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Увы-увы");
        }
    }

    boolean open() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:DB.db");
            System.out.println("Открылась ");
            return (true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    void close() {
        try {
            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Не закрылся");
        }
    }
}
```

Но у меня выдается ошибка

> java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4ResultSet.unused(JDBC4ResultSet.java:347) at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4ResultSet.updateString(JDBC4ResultSet.java:535) at testanddelete.TestAndDelete.change(TestAndDelete.java:35) at testanddelete.TestAndDelete.main(TestAndDelete.java:13)

Мне сказали, что это связано с тем, что библиотека SQLite не поддерживает команды

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Учитесь читать джавадоки! Метод [`updateRow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#updateRow()) интерфейса `ResultSet`:

```java
/**
 * . . .
 *
 * @exception SQLFeatureNotSupportedException if the JDBC driver does not support
 * this method
 * @since 1.2
 */
void updateRow() throws SQLException;
```

т. е. ошибка [`SQLException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html) выбрасывается в случае, если JDBC driver не поддерживает этот метод. Теперь открываем [`имплементацию`](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) этого метода для **SQLite**. Класс [`JDBC4ResultSet`](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sqlite/jdbc4/JDBC4ResultSet.java):

```java
protected SQLException unused() {
    return new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException();
}

. . .

public void updateRow() throws SQLException {
    throw unused();
}
```

т. е. в данной имплементации метод не используется - сразу выбрасывает [`SQLException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html).